# Unable to remove deleted post in GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

Creating a blog with Gatsby and Contentful. I deleted a post on Contentful but the post is still showing on GraphQL. Do I have any way to automatically remove deleted posts from GraphQL server?

I tried Mutation, but it did not work for me.

```
export const query = graphql`
  query($skip: Int!, $limit: Int!) {
    allContentfulPost(
      sort: { fields: [publishDate], order: DESC }
      limit: $limit
      skip: $skip
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          title
          id
          slug
          publishDate(formatString: "DD MMM YYYY")
          heroImage {
            title
            fluid(maxWidth: 1800) {
              ...GatsbyContentfulFluid_withWebp_noBase64
            }
          }
          body {
            childMarkdownRemark {
              html
              excerpt(pruneLength: 80)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`


export default Index
```

```
query MyQuery {
  contentfulBlogPost {
    id
  }
  allContentfulPost {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
        slug
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the node that I want to delete from GraphQL.

```
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "4e6323f0-87c9-53a3-b1bb-e357d8ae578f",
            "title": "test",
            "slug": "tesrt"
          }
        },
```

Comment: Did you run `gatsby build` again?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. After a while, it was removed from GraphQL, but I'm not sure why as I did not do anything after all. Anyway, thank you again for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Could be that the result is being cached, try running `gatsby clean`. [Documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-cli/#clean).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. After a while, it was removed from GraphQL, but I'm not sure why as I did not do anything after all. Anyway, thank you again for your suggestion.